# Why do we need webhooks where API could do everything webhook could do?

Tags: php, rest, api, http, webhooks

I read all possible information about webhook that I found, but there is no answer about why to use webhooks instead of Https Request which is much easier.

I built API that needs to notify users' server when the certain action happened on my server. Users provide me a URL and I need to send Webhooks or HTTP Post Request to that specific URL.

I can use cron jobs and send HTTP post request when something new happened on the server. Why do I need to use webhooks, if there is a more easy way to do this?

What is the advantage of webhooks over API request? What will be the benefit of using Webhooks over HTTP POST REQUESTS?

Comment: URL that user provided @IłyaBursov I updated the post to make it clear

Comment: A webhook *is* an HTTP request; arguably even an API request. The difference is which direction the request goes.

Comment: The root of my question is to learn why most systems require  `file_get_contents('php://input');` instead of `$_POST`. Why do Webhooks exist where we could simply send **curl** post requests. Is it more secure, or have any benefit because we could lose some customers if we force them to learn webhook concept @deceze

Comment: The root of your question is a misunderstanding. Your "simply send curl post requests" **is still a webhook**.

Comment: This is merely a technical limitation **of PHP** of how to read the POST body data. If the webhook sends JSON data, PHP won’t automatically parse it into the `$_POST` variable. That’s all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Webhooks allow one site to *notify* another site of something that happened, in real-time (or near-real-time).

As an example, let's say my app integrates with Facebook, and I want to know when a new comment is posted to a Facebook Page.

Without webhooks, I have to regularly check *every single post that Page ever made* for new comments. If they have a thousand posts, and I check every five minutes, that's twelve **thousand** API calls every hour... *forever*.

With webhooks, Facebook tells my server via a `POST` "hey there was a new comment on post #12345" once, when the comment is created.

Comment: @Ibrahim Hasanov, so you are implementing Webhooks by letting your client specify a URL.  But you are still making a regular HTTP post to their server when the necessary event happens.

Comment: But Why I don't send HTTP Request with the specific data they want me to send to the specific URL that they provided when something happened on my side?

Comment: @Ibrahim I don't understand the question. Please describe what *you* think a webhook is.

Comment: With HTTP POST request, Facebook could say your server "hey there was a new comment on post #12345" once when the comment is created. It will only send the same POST request

Comment: That's... what a webhook is. Webhooks **are** HTTP POST requests. You're describing exactly what a webhook does.

Comment: The problem is some developers need to learn webhooks, For example: they should learn that they should write following code to accept data `$request = file_get_contents('php://input');`, but they could use regular $_POST variable if we sent HTTP POST request which could be easy

Comment: Again, you're not really making sense. You're describing a simple stylistic choice - some apps send webhook data as the POST body, others send it as form data. Both are valid, both are doable, and both are easy to handle.

Comment: My question is why we need to send webhooks and write & learn `file_get_contents('php://input');`  instead of just sending HTTP POST **curl** request with data

Comment: And the answer is "because that's how that site's webhooks work".

Comment: But if we sent **curl** post request, they could just use `$_POST` to accept data, which is very familiar for beginner programmers

Comment: If you're building a webhook system, you can build it any way you like. If you're *using* someone else's webhooks, you have to do it their way. Webhooks aren't really a "beginner programmer" sort of thing; you're expected to at least be able to follow a simple documentation example.

Comment: Thanks. The root of my question is to learn why most systems require  `file_get_contents('php://input');` instead of `$_POST`. Why do Webhooks exist where we could simply send **curl** post requests. Is it more secure, or have any benefit because we could lose some customers if we force them to learn webhook concept @deceze

Comment: First, `file_get_contents('php://input')` is still handling a POST request, just a slightly different style of sending the data. Second, **both methods of sending the POST data are still "webhooks"**. You're making a distinction that doesn't exist. "Webhook" is a technique, not a particular technological implementation. You could send data with a GET request and it'd **still be a webhook**.

Comment: @ceejayoz the last comment was very helpful thank you! I thought it is kind of new technological implementation